# conda use a newer version of glibc

Tags: conda, glibc

I am deploying a R script from within a conda environment on a cluster. The script loads a few packages that require glibc version >= 2.14. While my system has glibc version 2.14, the cluster has a glibc version 2.12 and I get the following error:

`/lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by...)`

How can I tell conda to use a later version of glibc that is in my system library?

So far I have added a line in my cluster submission script to set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be the same as my system's library path. This failed and the glibc version remains 2.12 as seen using `conda info`.

I also tried adding an environmental variable `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/libc.so.6` before the execution of my script. However this gave me a segmentation fault error.

I have also tried a solution from this previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55663007/5110907). However, I get an error saying that my `make and gawk are too old`. And I do not have root privileges to do anything about this.

Please help me with this.

Comment: What are the packages?

Comment: The tidyverse package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

Answer (score 1):

> However this gave me a segmentation fault error.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explains why mismatch between `ld-linux` and `libc.so.6` results in errors (segmentaion fault is one frequent class), and what to do about it.

Setting `LD_PRELOAD` can't fix this.